# Propriedade computada Polymer

Tags: propriedade, polymer

Saudações.
Meu problema é o seguinte. Tenho uma página de detalhes do produto. Ela é acessada após clicar num produto específico em outra página de listagem, é exibido o conteúdo através do ID do produto. Até aí tudo bem. Dentro dessa página de detalhe, tenho um elemento  onde coloco informações sobre o produto naquela plataforma de venda. Esse elemento pede 5 propriedades básicas (logo, nome, descricao, url e preco). Consigo mostrar os dados sem problemas quando faço o caminho básico do firebase {{item.platform.plataforma.value}} , porém quero manipular o valor que está vindo e formatá-lo, mas quando faço a propriedade computada ela não retorna valor. Estou usando a mesma tática para a listagem dos produtos e tem funcionado por lá.

```
<template is="dom-if" if={{item.platform.teste.url}}>
   <box-plataforma logo="*imagem*" nome="{{nome}}" descricao="{{descricao}}" url="{{item.platform.teste.url}}" preco="{{item.platform.teste.value}}"></box-plataforma>
</template>
```

Quando utilizo o exemplo acima o valor é exibido normalmente.
Porém quando uso o código abaixo é retornado valor vazio para o preço que é o que desejo formatar.

```
<template is="dom-if" if={{item.platform.teste.url}}>
   <box-plataforma logo="*imagem*" nome="{{nome}}" descricao="{{descricao}}" url="{{item.platform.teste.url}}" preco="{{valueTeste}}"></box-plataforma>
</template>
```

O valor que deixo no properties é o seguinte:

```
valueTeste: {
  type: String,
  computed: 'pricePlatform(item.platform.teste.value)'
}
```

E a função para transformar o valor é:

```
pricePlatform(value) {
 if (value == undefined) {
  value = 0;
 }
 return (value != 0) ? '$ ' + value.toFixed(2).replace('.', ',') : 'Grátis'
}
```

Desde já grato, e caso faltem informações ou não esteja bem claro o que desejo peço desculpas, não sou muito experiente e não sei muitos termos específicos.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, ao invés de criar propriedades computadas fiz uma função

```
_pricePlatform(preco) {
    if (preco == undefined) {
      preco = 0;
    }
    return (preco != 0) ? 'R$ ' + preco.toFixed(2).replace('.', ',') : 'Grátis'
  }
```

e no elemento usei algo que a documentação do Polymer chama de "Computed binding" [aqui](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#annotated-computed)

```
<box-plataforma logo="*imagem*" nome="Teste" descricao="Teste" url="{{item.platform.teste.url}}" preco="{{_pricePlatform(item.platform.teste.value)}}"></box-plataforma>
```